# Keep Columns still while scrolling up and down. Excel 2010

Tags: excel-2010

Looking to keep Columns A-C stay still whole scrolling up and down. My worksheet has a lot of information on it and i need the first columns to stay still. I've tried freezing panes, but the columns only stay still when i scroll left and right, not up and down.
Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

To keep an area of a worksheet visible while you scroll to another area of the worksheet, you can lock specific rows or columns in one area by freezing or splitting panes.

When you freeze panes, you keep specific rows or columns visible when you scroll in the worksheet. For example, you might want to keep row and column labels visible as you scroll.

A solid line indicates that row 1 is frozen to keep column labels in place when you scroll.

When you split panes, you create separate worksheet areas that you can scroll within, while rows or columns in the non-scrolled area remain visible.

https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Freeze-or-lock-rows-and-columns-3439cfe6-010c-4d2d-a3c9-d0e8ba62d724

Comment: I tried freezing (as i already stated), and it doesnt work. I tried splitting, but it still scrolls down while i scroll my other info.